# Give an example to show that when A is a subspace of topological space X and S $\subset$ A ,cl(S$^A$) need not be the same as the set S

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Give an example to show that when A is a subspace of topological space X and S $\subset$ A ,cl(S$^A$) need not be the same as the set S

**Here is my approach**

Cl(S$^A$)=Cl($S_A$)

So let X=R with lower limit topology  with the subspace A=(1,3).
Let S=(2,2$\frac{1}{4}$) then S$\subset$A

So Cl(S$^A$)=(1,3] $\cap$ A and it’s closure in S is the set [2,2$\frac{1}{4}$ ] $\cap$ A

I am basing my example off
[Example on closure of a subset of a subspace of a topological space in Munkres's Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/641571/919044)

But I can’t figure out the rest.lt seems a bit nebulous.

Any help to solve it would be appreciated.

Source:*A First Course in Topolog*y:Conover

Comment: What is $S^A$?.

Comment: First S$\subset$ X we have denoted the closure of S by cl(S)
Let X be a topological space.let A $\subset$ X have the relative  topology inherited from the topology on Xif S $\subset $ A cl(S$^A$)=cl(S) $\cap$ A

Comment: I still don't understand.  Is $S^A$ notation for $\mathrm{cl}(S) \cap A$?

Comment: Yes . If S $\subset$ A then it could have two meanings closure of A wrt to X or closure of A wrt to X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cl$(S^A)$, the closure of $S$ in the space $A$, is more commonly written cl$_A(S).$ Some prefer to write Cl for cl.

Directly from the definition of "subspace topology" it follows that if $A$ is a subspace of $X$ and if $S\subset A$ then we have cl$_A(S)=A\cap$ cl$_X(S).$

Suppose $S\subsetneqq$ cl$_X(S)\subset A.$  Then cl$_A(S)=A\cap$ cl$_X(S)=$ cl$_X(S)\ne S.$

E.g. if $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual topology, $A=(0,3)$, and $S=(1,2).$

We also often have cl$_A(S)\ne$ cl$_X(S).$ E.g. any space is a closed subset of itself, so if $A=S$ and if $A$ is not a closed subset of $X$ then cl$_A(S)=$ cl$_A(A)= A\ne$ cl$_X(A)=$ cl$_X(S).$

It is useful to remember that if S and A are both closed in X and if S $\subset$ A then  S is closed in A.

Comment: Is it possible to have an example if X=R with lower limit topology?